# Grab current image from UIScrollView, change into black and white, then display back in scroll view

Tags: swift, swift2

I am trying to grab the current zoomed image from the scrollView, crop it to the current frame, change it to black and white, then redisplay the cropped image to the scrollView in black and white.

After I run my code below (from buttonAction), the scrollView doesn't seem to be displaying anything, but I can still scroll and zoom on a non-existant image. There are no compile errors/warnings or seg faults.

Any idea where I went wrong?

```
func grabImageFromCurrentView() -> UIImage {
    // grab image from current zoom

    // Note: "CIImage(image: imageToChange)" fails later on if the "false" here is set to true
    // it has something to do with setting the image to RGBA instead of RGB
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scrollView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    let offset =  scrollView.contentOffset

    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y)
    scrollView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}

// turn image to black and white image
func setNoirFilter(imageToChange: UIImage) -> UIImage  {

    let originalFrameImage = CIImage(image: imageToChange)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectNoir")
    filter?.setDefaults()
    filter?.setValue(originalFrameImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let imageOutput = filter!.outputImage


    let image = UIImage(CIImage: imageOutput!)

    return image
}

func displayImage(image: UIImage) {
    let originalImage = image

    imageView.image = originalImage
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height)

    scrollView.contentSize = originalImage.size

    let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleHeight, scaleWidth)

    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 50 // set so high for high resolution images I'll be using
    scrollView.zoomScale = minScale

    centerScrollViewContents()
}

@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let currentViewImage = grabImageFromCurrentView()

    let blackAndWhiteImage = setNoirFilter(currentViewImage)

    displayImage(blackAndWhiteImage)
}
```

Comment: Try using some breakpoints to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still have no idea why what I had wasn't working, but somehow the 'image' in the setNoirFilter would become deallocated. It doesn't make sense, I used the exact same code in a new project and it worked just fine.

However, thanks to [this guy](http://myxcode.net/2015/08/30/converting-an-image-to-black-white-in-swift/) I was able to substitute my setNoirFilter function with this and it works just fine.

```
func convertToGrayScale(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let imageRect:CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
    let width = image.size.width
    let height = image.size.height

    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.None.rawValue)
    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(width), Int(height), 8, 0, colorSpace, bitmapInfo.rawValue)

    CGContextDrawImage(context, imageRect, image.CGImage)
    let imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
    let newImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef!)

    return newImage
}
```